# Discord.js question about interaction. is not a function. Why?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a code:

```
client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async (interaction) => {
    console.log('interaction.isCommand() ' , interaction.isCommand());
}
```

But I am getting error on interaction:

`TypeError: interaction.isCommand is not a function`

why is it happening? I still cant understand that issue.
"discord.js": "^14.9.0",

I want to make interaction.reply()

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I solved this.

just made this:

```
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    console.log('interaction.commandName ' , interaction.commandName);
}
```